# Array returning only end value in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to return the entire path traced by Djikstra's algorithm using an array but somehow it's returning only the end node, but when i print the value in the same method it's printing correct values.

```
public int[] PrintPath(int[] path, int j, int src)
        {
            int[] trace = new int[14];
            int i = 0;

            if (path[j] == -1)
                return path;


            PrintPath(path, path[j], src);
            Console.Write("{0}", j + 1);
            trace[i] = j + 1;
            i++;
            return trace;
        }//PrintPath
```

source node: 1, destination node: 10

expected output: 1 13 7 9 10

actual array output: 0 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

Comment: Could you please explain the problem in more detail

Comment: why dont you debug your method and check what is caused to your problem?

Comment: i've used djikstra's algorithm and in the method posted above it's printing the shortest path it took to reach the destination. I'm trying to store all these nodes in an array and pass it to another function. But, only the end node/vertex is getting stored in the entire array.

Comment: give example what your call what you expect and what the result

Comment: Please provide the input data in valid C# code and what you expect the output should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is definitely not clear.
If you just want to print the path why don't you use `String.Join(" ", path)` ?

i.e.

```
int[] path = new int[] {1, 13, 7, 9, 10 };      
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", path));
```

Or please explain well what is your goal.